# Create vertical tab menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, menu, tabs

I need create the following tab menu. Could you give me some tips or show some examples on fiddle? Thanks for any suggestion.

[image: tab menu]

EDIT..  I need create top and bottom arrows

```css
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    }

.tabs a {
    display: block;
    width:110px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #dde2e4;
    color: #19305a;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 13px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tabs a.active {
    background: #fff;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1">Process Data</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2" class="active">Requested Information</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3">General Structure</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab4">Client Details</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: We aren't a code writing service. Please show us effort and give us a specific question and we'll be glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see in utilizing pure CSS (and no filler elements) would be in creating both the top AND bottom arrows alongside a border.  Typically a solution for an arrow with border utilizes both the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes.

If you're willing to forgo one of the arrows, a possible solution can be viewed here:

http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/grRqXq

Comment: Thank you :) This is exactly what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

something like that ? Giving you some code won't help you...

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#process">Process Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#request">Requested Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#general">General Structure</a></li>
  <li><a href="#client">Client Details</a></li>
</ul>
```